# Can you help me understand these TAR, SPLIT commands?

Tags: bash, split, tar

What do these command lines mean?

1. `tar cvzf - ./android_4.0.4_origen_final_full/ | split -b 2048m - android_4.0.4_origen_final_full.tar.gz`
2. `cat android_4.0.4_origen_final_full.tar.gz* | tar -zxvpf - -C /work`

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with Android. It probably should be tagged bash/Linux

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Googling "man tar", "man split" and "man cat" for details on options and such.

`tar` is a program (`tar` originally was short for "tape archive") which creates a serial archive format. It's used to glob a whole directory structure full of files into a single archive file or onto a backup device (tape, disk, or whatever).

`split` will take a single file and break it into chunks of a given size.

```
tar cvzf - ./android_4.0.4_origen_final_full/ | split -b 2048m - android_4.0.4_origen_final_full.tar.gz
```

This command will create an archive of all the files under `./android_4.0.4_origen_final_full/` and, instead of creating a single archive file, breaks the results up (via `split`) into several 2,048MB (2GB) files. Specifically, the `c` option on `tar` means "create", `v` means "verbose" (you'll get an output line for each file archived), `z` means it will be compressed (with `gzip`), and `f` indicates the output file. Since the output file is given as `-`, then the output goes to the standard output (thus, it can be piped into `split`). The `split` option `-b 2048m` means the output will be split into 2GB sized files.  So if the archive is 3GB, you'll get one file that's 2GB, and one that 1GB.

```
cat android_4.0.4_origen_final_full.tar.gz* | tar -zxvpf - -C /work
```

This does the opposite of the first command. It concatenates all files in the current folder whose names start with `android_4.0.4_origen_final_full.tar.gz` and unarchives them with `tar`. The `tar` options are the same as above, but `x` means "extract", `p` means to "preserve" file permissions, and the `f -` means take the input from the standard input (from the `cat` command in this case), and the `C /work` tells tar to change to the `/work` directory for the extraction.

Answer (score 0):

The first command creates multiple tar.gz files split on 2KB blocks while the second command extracts the contents of the tart.gz file into the /work directory. It uses pipes "|" to connect one shell command's output to the input (stdin) of another.

```
tar cvzf - ./android_4.0.4_origen_final_full/
```

creates tar files (a file with all data lined up contiguously) of everything under the android_4.0.4_origen_final_full folder and compresses the tar file with gzip compression giving it an extra .gz extension. The output is piped or sent to the following command.

```
split -b 2048m -
```

splits input supplied on stdin (from the prior tar command) on 2KB blocks creating individual tar gripped files with the base name:
android_4.0.4_origen_final_full.tar.gz

```
cat android_4.0.4_origen_final_full.tar.gz*
```

dump the raw contents of the filename parameter to the screen or (stdout)

```
tar -zxvpf - -C /work
```

Extract everything from its input (stdin) to the /work folder